# JavaScript mask to Code Area only

Tags: javascript, meiomask

I'm trying to set a mask to code area, but the right parentheses never appears.

```
       $("#dddResponsavel").setMask({
            mask : '(99)',
            autoTab : false
        });
```

It should be like (31) or (15), but when I run the project, only appears (31 or (15 ...

Comment: I feel like your tags and description could have been a bit more specific to what you are using. `setMask` is not really something that is built-into JavaScript

Comment: have you tried something along the lines of `mask : '(99\)',` ?

Comment: @Christian Scillitoe: Yes I've tried mask: '(99\)', and still not working.

Comment: @apokryfos :
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#cpf").setMask({
                mask : '999.999.999-99',
                autoTab : false
            });
            $("#dddResponsavel").setMask({
                mask : '(99)',
                autoTab : false
            });

            $("#telefoneResponsavel").setMask({
                mask : '99999-9999',
                autoTab : false
            });
        });
All the other masks works.

Comment: What's `$` and where does `.setMask` come from? Aren't those details worth mentioning in the question?

Comment: $ comes from jQuery. .setMask come from jquery-meiomask lib.

Comment: @SauloLauers I played around with meiomask a bit and got the same results as you, maybe its a bug with the package. Possibly consider looking at the source and fixing it and opening a PR or using a different masking library.

Comment: It was solved using the mask at same filed for number and code area... so my mask is  $("#telefoneResponsavel").setMask({ mask : '(99) 99999-9999', autoTab : false });